# ngClick on mdListItem and secondary button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I use angular-material (1.0.7) on my project and I would like to create a clickable list (copied from the official doc) with secondary button.

The main issue is the list-item clickable event is also fired when I click on secondary button. In the doc, they show a dialog with targetEvent but it is not what I try to do.

There is my code:

```
            <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="tag in tagsCtrl.showedTags|orderBy:'title'" ng-click="tagsCtrl.navigate(tag)">
                <ng-md-icon icon="label"></ng-md-icon>
                <div class="md-list-item-text">
                    <h3>{{ tag.title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ tag.slug }}</p>
                </div>
                <span class="md-secondary" ng-show="tag.onProcess">
                    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="24"></md-progress-circular>
                </span>

                <span class="md-secondary" ng-hide="tag.onProcess">
                    <md-button class=" md-icon-button md-hue-3" ng-click="tagsCtrl.editTag(tag, $event)" aria-label="Edit tag">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="create"></ng-md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                    <md-button class=" md-icon-button md-hue-3" ng-click="tagsCtrl.deleteTag(tag)" aria-label="Delete tag">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="delete"></ng-md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                </span>
            </md-list-item>
```

The navigation function is not a dialog.
Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood it right, but you should stop the propagation of the event from bubbling to its parent (in this case from the `md-button` to the `md-list-item`)

Check more documentation here [jQuery event.stopPropagation() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp)

So where you **have**:

```
ng-click="tagsCtrl.editTag(tag, $event)"
ng-click="tagsCtrl.deleteTag(tag)"
```

you can **replace** with

```
ng-click="tagsCtrl.editTag(tag, $event) && $event.stopPropagation()"
ng-click="tagsCtrl.deleteTag(tag) && $event.stopPropagation()"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So easy in fact but never though about it. `ng-click="tagsCtrl.editTag(tag, $event); $event.stopPropagation();"`

Comment: I am glad it helped you :) Have a nice weekend :)

Comment: It really works like a charm. Have a nice weekend too :)